# Save Javascript variable value and read it in python

Tags: javascript, python

I have 2 devices connected to my machine  with rs232 usb connection. One is listed as `ttyUSB0` and the other is `ttyUSB1`. In `findDevice` function I find one of them.

```
device2 = port.comName;
```

I have a python code to find the other one:

How can I use the result of `findDevice` in the python code to avoid doing the test for both `ttyUSB0` and `ttyUSB1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about javascript but if you return a value from the function you can use `subprocess.check_output` to run the javascript from python using nodejs:

```
from subprocess import check_output


res = check_output(["nodejs","path_to/test.js"])
```

`test.js`:

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

Output:

```
res = check_output(["nodejs","test.js"])
print(res)
b'Hello World\n'
```